# Scrapy handling cookies/sessions/proxies

Tags: python, session-cookies, scrapy

I am working on a spider that crawls a site while authenticated, it uses multiple users and multiple proxies. Is there anyway I could handle cookies, proxies and session so each user uses their specific cookie with a specific proxy so there is no problems crawling things?

At the moment I am able to crawl with one user while authenticated and single IP, but want to do this with more users.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, though it will require some work.

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

1. Tweaking every `Request` and `Response` manually, which might seem simpler
2. Writing a middleware, which is more complex, but more universal

In both cases this info should help:

- using [dont_merge_cookies](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-meta-special-keys) and [CookieJar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6437196/248296)
- you can [set a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10849429/248296) per request